# Is it a good naming convention to name your custom classes the same as the file name in Swift/iOS

Tags: ios, swift, class

I just created my first custom Swift class and I noticed that it didn't add the class name when I ceated the swift file, in fact the only thing in that file is the import statement for the foundation. If I'm not mistaken Xcode copies the file name when you create Obj-C classes.

Is it a good naming convention to name your custom classes the same as the file name in Swift/iOS?

Comment: If you start typing the class name as the file name it will usually auto complete for you.

Comment: Did you create a Swift File, or a Cocoa/Cocoa Touch class? Creating a Cocoa/Cocoa Touch class will fill in the class name for you.

Comment: @thefredelement - I don't think it autocompletes the name, it least it didn't work for me. Thanks

Comment: @Siriss - I created a Swift file since I want a custom class, but now that you touched on this subject, how do you start your custom classes, as an empty Swift file or as Cocoa Touch class which sublclasses from NSObject? Does that matters if I create it as Cocoa Touch and I don't use any of the NSObject features? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, just like in other languages, it is good practice to name the file the same as the class. It avoids confusion and makes it clear.

Comment: first of all thank you for the clarification. Quick question: How do you normally start your custom classes, as an empty Swift file or as Cocoa Touch class which subclasses from NSObject? Does that matters if I create it as Cocoa Touch and I don't use any of the NSObject features?

Comment: I always start with a Cocoa Touch subclass. It saves a few minutes of typing.

Comment: I guess you save time on the class name but when you start a class by subclassing Cocoa Touch, it imports Cocoa instead of Foundation and you end it up deleting and typing Foundation. FYI - Here I'm referring to a custom class that only does calculations.

Answer (score 3):

Yes it is a good practice. If the IDE doesn't do it, do it yourself for the sake of your sanity. I don't want to open a project with tens of classes where the class `Person` is defined in `file1.swift`.

Comment: Thank you! It's exactly what I thought, that would be a nightmare.